# Parsing text using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following text which will always follow the same format:

```
 1
 "13"
 "241"
 "Rabun"
 "06"
 "County"

 2
 "13"
 "281"
 "Towns"
 "06"
 "County"
```

I would like to assign each section to a hash like:

```
locality= {:id => "", :fips1 => "", :fips2 => "", :county => "", :stateid => "", :type => ""}
```

How would I go about doing this in Ruby? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fields = [:fips1,:fips2,:county,:stateid,:type]
arraywithhashes = yourtextdata.split("\n\n").map { |loc|
    Hash[
        [[:id,loc[/\d+/]]] +
        fields.zip(loc.scan(/"([^"]+)"/).map &:first)
    ]
}
```

If you add new fields to your file, the only you'll need to edit is to add it to `fields`.

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: Then learn it! After a while you'd rather starve than code Java...

Comment: The data is coming from a text file so if I do

textfile = File.open("filename.dat")

arraywithhashes = textfile.split("\n\n").map { |loc|

I get a NoMethodError.

Comment: @Lars Haugseth - I'm trying to! Even joined a Open Source project :)

Comment: @Mike, `file = File.open('filename.dat'); textfile = file.read;  file.close` or `textfile = File.open('filename.dat'){|f|f.read}` or `textfile = File.read('filename.dat')`

Comment: This just gives me the 1st text block of the text file.It doesn't seem to loop through the rest of the text blocks.

Comment: @Mike, check your file to have `\n\n` delimeter between blocks. If it is another, edit `split` parameters.

Comment: Yes. it does have \n\n delimeters and still no luck. This seems to be a very generic solution but it's not working out for me.

Comment: OK, your file had `\n \n `. Hex-viewers are usefull.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nakilon. It worked great! Thanks for taking the extra time to look at the txt file too. I've added a hex-viewer to my toolset now.

Answer (score 0):

for each section, use a regular expression with groups corresponding to each entry in the section, then simply create hash table as you described from these groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
locality.each_key { |k| locality.store(k, "foo") }
```

Another newbie-ish person here, but that might be a start for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a Struct instead of a Hash.

```
Locality = Struct.new(:id, :fips1, :fips2, :county, :stateid, :type)
localities = []
DATA.each_slice(7) do |chunk|
    chunk.pop if chunk.size == 7 
    localities << Locality.new(*chunk.map{|line| line.scan(/\w+/) })
end

p localities # => [#<struct Locality id=["1"], fips1=["13"], fips2=["241"], etc. 
puts localities[1].fips2 # => 281

__END__
1
 "13"
 "241"
 "Rabun"
 "06"
 "County"

 2
 "13"
 "281"
 "Towns"
 "06"
 "County"
```

- each_slice(7) takes 7 lines of
  DATA (the stuff after `__END__` ).
- The last line is removed unless there
  are only six lines (the last
  'record').
- A cleaned-up copy of the remaining 
  lines is made. With these values a 
  new Locality is created and added to 
  an array